# Exponential of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

> If $u_A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^nA^nu}{n!}$ is converge, $u_A=e^{iA}u$.

I cannot prove this. I will appreciate your help with this situation.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Where are you getting stuck?  What is your definition of $e^X$ in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sup_{\|u\| \leq 1}\| \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} \frac {i^{n}A^{n}u} {n!}\| \leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} \frac {\|A\|^{n}} {n!}\to 0$ as $m >n \to \infty$. Hence the sereies converges in operator norm (and sum is defined as $e^{iA}$).

Comment: Thanks, I get it.